# Associating HTML's deleteRow() with a table generated by PHP

Tags: php, html, html-lists

I have the following PHP code to generate a table where there are rows whose columns have the following attributes: "id", "lastname", and "firstname". I want to add a button for each of the rows that deletes the respective row and have this line to attempt to do so: `echo '<td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow('+$i+')"></td>';` in the following code. However, it's printing the value of $i (1,2,3,4,... which are the row numbers I want associated with the buttons) instead of having delete buttons dedicated to each row (with the follow code below, it doesn't create any buttons unless I specifically remove the `'+$i+'` part). What is the issue?

```
<table>
                <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td>id</td>
                <td>Last Name</td>
                <td>First Name</td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            $i = 1;
            foreach ( $names['result'] as $a ){       // $a is an array    
                echo '<tr>';
                echo '<td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow('+$i+')"></td>';   // issue is here
                echo '<td>' . $q['id'] . '</td>';
                echo '<td>' . $q['lastName'] . '</td>'; 
                echo '<td>' . $q['firstName'] . '</td>';
                echo '</tr>';
            }
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `.` is the string concatenation operator in `php` language whereas the `+` is a concatenation operator in `javascript` language.

You should use `onclick="deleteRow('.$i.')"`

And then, just before ending the loop, just use a `$i++;`